# Blur event cancels Click events with jQuery on Mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, events

I have a blur event in a textarea:

```
$("#question-id-5-answer").blur(function (event) {}
```

And a click event in the Submit button:

```
$("#" + _sendBtnId).on("click", function () {}
```

It happens that the Click event does not fire because the Blur event cancel the click event.

I can't use the Mousedown event because it's a touch device that does not detect it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried saving the following on my mobile device as a htm file and accessed using Forefox application. Appears to be working as expected. Please have a look if it helps you.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <textarea id="myTxt"></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="butSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myTxt").blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() != "") {
            alert("retunging false");
            return false;   
        }

        alert("rextarea is empty");
    });

    $("#butSubmit").click(function() {
        alert("submitted");
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but how do I know if the user has click the button?

Comment: Blur would be returned false if textarea is not empty (ie. it has values); while you can still add functionality of button-onClick to do the needful fur submission. I believe this should work on the mobile device as well.

Comment: But the blur event stops the click event from firing

Comment: I've added the script that worked for me on my Android phone. The submit button click is also fired after going through the blur event (when returned false).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tggL5zma/ in your example, if I am with the focus inside the textarea and I press Submit, the submit click does not fire up

Comment: Just tried it on my mobile and upon submit button press, I can see `Submitted` alert box popping after the blur alerts are over.  As a matter of fact, I felt I need to add some condition checks to stop it from firing always. I wonder why its different in your case. (I'm using Android and tested it with Firefox and Dolphin mini browser). :)